# Prolog : Ordering a list alphabetically

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, prolog-setof

I have the following problem, i'm supposed to order a List containing only Strings in alphabetical order using only 'bagof', 'findall', 'setoff' , i am not suposed to use any sort of  sorting algorithm.

Here is the content of the .pl document i have to make the list with.

```
musico('R. Stevie Moore').
musico('Lane Steinberg').
musico('Yukio Yung').
musico('Jessie Evans').
musico('Miguel').
musico('Lucia Pamela').
musico('Shooby Taylor').
musico('Tiny Tim').
musico('The Legendary Stardust Cowboy').
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
all_musicians([Z]) :-
    findall(X, musico(X), Z).
```

This makes the list containing all musicians, but now i cant seem to understand how to order it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `setof` is `bagof` + `sort`. But why did you not read the documentation of `setof` and `bagof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setof/3` is what you want, since it produces a sorted list of results.

```
all_musicians(Z) :- 
    setof(X, musico(X), Z).
```

Comment: Can setof be used to sort all types of Lists containing only one kind of variables?
What if the List contains multiple types of variables?

Comment: @eXistanCe Just read the documentation, in particular how `sort/2` sorts and what "standard order of terms" means.

Comment: @eXistanCe yes, `setof/3` or `sort/2` can sort all kinds of list elements. You should read the documentation which explains rules for [Standard Order of Terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder).